# jq: Remove keys with empty string values

Tags: json, key, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 1",
      "{#ID}": "1",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.2:80"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 2",
      "{#ID}": "2",
      "{#IP}": ""
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 3",
      "{#ID}": "3",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.3:80"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 4",
      "{#ID}": "4",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.4:80"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 5",
      "{#ID}": "5",
      "{#IP}": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 1",
      "{#ID}": "1",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.2"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 2",
      "{#ID}": "2",
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 3",
      "{#ID}": "3",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.3"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 4",
      "{#ID}": "4",
      "{#IP}": "192.168.1.4"
    },
    {
      "{#NAME}": "Test 5",
      "{#ID}": "5",
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm very new to using JQ and not sure how I can go about doing this. I read through this [issue page on GitHub](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104) but none of the example seem to work for me.

I also need to remove the port number and colon. Is that possible?

Comment: I wouldn't use JQ for this; nodejs will be easier:
`node -e "x = $(cat data.json); x.data.forEach(o => { if(o['{#IP}'] == '') delete o['{#IP}']; else o['{#IP}'] = o['{#IP}'].split(':')[0]; }); console.log(x)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do below, to select values that are not *empty* using `with_entries(expr)`, with the *expr* being the condition that excludes the empty fields.

Also use the `.value` field again to remove the string that matches the regex containing the port string.

```
jq '.data |= map(with_entries(select(.value != "") | .value |= sub(":[0-9][0-9]$"; "")))'
```

[jqplay - Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IPIqtH9fDR)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much, this is perfect. I only made one change so that I will catch port numbers that are any length.

`.data |= map(with_entries(select(.value != "") | .value |= sub(":[0-9]+$"; "")))`

Answer (score -1):

Delete all lines which ends with `""`:

```
sed -r '/""$/d' test.json
```

Comment: that is not a universal solution - e.g.: it'll won't work if JSON is formatted in a way where values are on the separate lines with the keys.

Comment: OP asked for a solution using `jq` that reads JSON regardless if prettified, not using `sed` that assumes specific formatting.