# How to handle empty string in jq

Tags: jq

I have a jq command like so:

```
jq '.SecurityGroups[] | {name: .GroupName, groupid: .GroupId, ips: .IpPermissions[].IpRanges[].CidrIp, sourcegroup: .IpPermissions[].UserIdGroupPairs[].GroupId}'
```

It works well except for one thing. It doesn't seem to handle having that value not exist. It only returns when all values exist.

**Expected Output**:

```
{
  "name": "group1",
  "groupid": "sg-012345",
  "ips": "10.0.0.0/8",
  "sourcegroup": ""           # having this value not return at all would suffice
}
{
  "name": "group2",
  "groupid": "sg-06789",
  "ips": "",                  # having this value not return at all would suffice
  "sourcegroup": "sg-abcd"
}
{
  "name": "group3",
  "groupid": "sg-xyz",
  "ips": "192.0.0.0/8",
  "sourcegroup": "sg-xyz"
}
```

**JSON Input**:

```
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "GroupName": "group1",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                },
            "GroupId": "sg-012345",
        },
        {
            "GroupName": "group2",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-abcd",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            "GroupId": "sg-06789",
        },
        {
            "GroupName": "group3",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "192.0.0.0/8"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-xyz",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            "GroupId": "sg-xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found the following but I can't see to get it to work for my situation so not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

[jq: Remove keys with empty string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63635682/jq-remove-keys-with-empty-string-values)

Comment: The JSON input is invalid here.

Answer (score 0):

Although your JSON is invalid, you can probably achieve what you need using the alternative operator `//`. Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
$ jq . test.json
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
      {
        "c": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": []
  }
]
$ jq '.[] | {aa: .a, bb: .b[].c}' test.json # attempt 1
{
  "aa": 1,
  "bb": 3
}
$ jq '.[] | {aa: .a, bb: (.b[].c // "")}' test.json # attempt 2
{
  "aa": 1,
  "bb": 3
}
{
  "aa": 2,
  "bb": ""
}
```

You can see that the second element's `b` array is empty, causing it to be omitted from the result in the first attempt which resembles your approach. In the second attempt, we used the alternative operator to coalesce to the empty string.

Deleting the nonexistent entries can be done multiple ways, for example:

```
$ jq '.[] 
  | {aa: .a, bb: (.b[].c // null)} 
  | if .bb == null then del(.bb) else . end
' test.json
{
  "aa": 1,
  "bb": 3
}
{
  "aa": 2
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about invalid json. I was editing out sensitive information so might have accidentally removed characters. 

I will give your suggestion a go later, thanks for the help!